# Is it possible to optimize a function with two variables (a continuous variable and a binary variable) in R with a GA algorithm?

Tags: r, optimization, data-science, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am a beginner in the use of genetic algorithms, in particular the GA algorithm.

I would like to know how to optimize a function with two independent variables with a GA algorithm.

my function is described as :

f(x,y)=x*(1+alpha*y)

x is a continuous variable;

y is a binary variable between 0 and 1;

alpha is a parameter varying between [-1,0].

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with making y continuous and just round before evaluating your function.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Finally, I used  type = "real-valued in ga  algorithm (package GA in R). Thanks